# Emacs Racer "can't find crate"

Tags: emacs, rust

I have a project set up that builds fine with `cargo build`, but when I open it in Emacs with rust-mode and racer-mode it gives the the error `can't find crate for whatever_dependency` for every single `extern crate whatever_dependency;` declaration. I assume this means that Racer is not finding my dependencies, so I was wondering if there's anything I need to do to tell Racer where to find them?

I've set `CARGO_HOME` to `/home/myUser/.cargo`, but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I was being stupid: it wasn't actually emacs-racer producing the error, it was flycheck mode. It's fixable by installing rust-flycheck.